# sending email with gmail smtp ( secure layer ) in c++

Tags: c++, smtp, gmail, ssl

does any one had success with gmail smtp servers ? smtp.gmail.com
to send emails from c++ code ? 
i know its using secure layer but i have no idea how to implement such one .

Comment: One thing you might want to know, I (and I've heard similarly from others) could never get it to work on port 465. Using port 587, which is the other port listed in the GMail docs seemed to work.

Comment: no problem i can use 587 port , but how my code needs to be to support secure layer

Answer (score 2):

This is what i used, It was for linux though, It should Technically work on windows

> http://johnwiggins.net/jwsmtp/

The Tutorials are there and straigt forwards

> http://johnwiggins.net/jwsmtp/example1.html

Here is a copy and paste from the site showing Ports and SMTP Server. Credit goes to john wiggins

```
     jwsmtp::mailer mail(to.c_str( ),
                     from.c_str( ),
                     subject.c_str( ),
                     mailmessage.c_str( ),
                     smtpserver.c_str( ),
                     jwsmtp::mailer::SMTP_PORT,
                     false);
```

To Authenticate

```
mail.username("loginname");
mail.password("secret");
mail.authtype(mailer::PLAIN);
```

Currently only LOGIN and PLAIN authentication are supported, LOGIN by default,
to set to PLAIN call the authtype function

Comment: ok i saw the source , in source it does not support authentication 
but in the web site its written that it does ...

Comment: now i figure i need STARTTLS ( ssl )_ support 
that this lib does not supprt , is there any solution ?

Comment: Try emailing the guy who wrote the lib.. he might be able to help you out on that. Or request an addition :D. It will be nice for all of us

Comment: looks useful... i wish boost had something like that

Answer (score 1):

Your ISP could be blocking the secure SMTP port.

You could try to the same in Thunderbird and verify that the port is open first.

Comment: thanks. that's noteworthy point. I don't see any reason for them to block, though.

Answer (score 0):

Sending to GMail over SSL connection on port 465 does work, and in a straightforward way. You establish connection, you do SSL initialization/handshake, then send `EHLO` command and it is the usual way from there. You also need login or plain authentication with the server to make it accept your messages.