# Send mail in c++ in windows using gmail as smtp relayer

Tags: c++

Does anyone know how  to send an email with an attachment(txt file) using a gmail as an smtp relayer in windows environment.I have looked at some sample code here but that was for the linux os. So far i could not find any sample code for windows.Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226213/sending-email-with-gmail-smtp-secure-layer-in-c

Comment: Check out POCO - http://pocoproject.org/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.I am currently checking it out.

Answer (score 1):

Google mail server will only accept secure connection, SSL or TLS. Here are the addresses and ports GMail uses: http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287

So, you need to use SSL/TLS-enabled socket like this one: [CSslSocket - SSL/TLS enabled CSocket](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1600/CSslSocket-SSL-TLS-enabled-CSocket).

Or, if you want to implement SMTP over SSL yourself, using `SChannel API`, this sample will guide you through: [C++ SSPI Schannel TLS example](http://www.coastrd.com/c-schannel-smtp) (this shows how to break through SSL and you are to complete with with SMTP plain text conversation sending an email).

Comment: I already have an account in gmail. I just want to know how to relay it through this account. I have tried jwsmtp but to no awail. I am unable to use it on windows. What else can i do?

Comment: To send through GMail server you need to establish a secure connection (this is where you need SSL/TLS), and authenticate with your Google account.